# How to get Data from Activity to RecyclerView Adapter Class using getIntent() method?

Tags: android-intent, android-recyclerview

I am creating an android app where there is button in each CardView in RecyclerView, which perform networking operation(call POST method) on Onclick() method, and i want user_id which is on, mainActivity ,so how to get that id from MainActivity to RecyclerView Adapter Class.

i have Already tried 
getIntent.getStringExtra();

also tried using Bundle:
Bundle b= context.getIntent.getExtra();
String s= b.getStringExtra("id");

but in both case getIntent method is not allowed.
Please Give your Suggestion.